# How to better take care of already answered questions?

Tags: bug

I posted a question which was already answered. As the 10th of 12 answers. Despite of my question precluding the 9 previous answers, it was still marked as "This question already has answers here" and now, after further research, I can't answer my own question.

But recently I've got a gold "Famous question" badge for that. So can I prevent other people from trying 9 wrong answers?

Comment: Can you give a link to the question?

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts…

1. Time isn’t always relevant to dupes. Sometimes (more on SO) if a newer question has many good answers and is highly upvoted, an an ancient dupe target is found, the old one may still be marked as a dupe of the new one.
2. RE wrong answers: downvote them. Do NOT flag as NAA. Wrong answers are still considered answers (for the NAA flag, anyways)
3. If you found an answer, post it on the question your question was made a dupe of. If you feel it isn’t a good dupe, edit your question to clarify why it isn’t, and it can be un-marked as a dupe (then you post your answer)